# Writing a LUA File from a NodeJS Application

Tags: node.js, lua

How can I write an LUA file from a NodeJS Application? Is there a templating engine like Handlebars, JADE/PUG, that I can use to make a template of my LUA file structure. And then add variables before the LUA file is written with the FS module.

Is there a way like that or do I have to do make it by hardcoding as a string?
I wanted the template with injecting values as in handlebars to be able to add as many templates.

Thanks

Comment: I personally haven't used it, but I know [this JS to Lua transpiler](https://github.com/PaulBernier/castl).

Comment: [*Lua](http://lua.org/about.html#name)